# Flutter switch button not updating

Tags: list, flutter, dart, button, switch-statement

I am new to flutter and have been trying to make a to-do list app for the past couple of days. I have been trying to implement a feature wherein the users can mark a task as important which then gets highlighted in the listview. But, in the page where I have placed the switch button, after switching, the button is not updated, even though the backend functionality is working and the task is getting marked as important. Can someone please help me with this ? This is the code : -

```
class toDoList extends StatefulWidget
{
    bool data = false;
    @override
    createState() 
    {
        return new toDoListState();
    }
}

class toDoListState extends State<toDoList>
{
  List<String> tasks = [];
  List<String> completedTasks = [];
  List<String> descriptions = [];
  List<bool> importance = [];
  
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context)
    {
        return Scaffold
        (
            body: buildToDoList(),
            floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton
            (
                onPressed: addToDoItemScreen, 
                tooltip: 'Add Task',
                child: new Icon(Icons.add),
            ),
        );
    }

    Widget buildToDoList()
    {
        return new ListView.builder
        (
            itemBuilder: (context, index)
            {
                if(index < tasks.length)
                {
                    return row(tasks[index], descriptions[index], index);
                }
            },
        );
    }

    Widget row(String task, String description, int index)
    {                  
        return Dismissible(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        background: Container(color: Colors.red, child: Align(alignment: Alignment.center, child: Text('DELETE', textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),))),
        direction: DismissDirection.horizontal,
        onDismissed: (direction) {
        setState(() {
          tasks.removeAt(index);
          if(completedTasks.contains(task))
          {
              completedTasks.removeAt(index);
          }
          descriptions.removeAt(index);
          importance.removeAt(index);
        });
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(task+" dismissed")));
        },
        child: CheckboxListTile(
          controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
          title: Text(task, style: (completedTasks.contains(task)) ? TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough) : TextStyle(),),
          subtitle: (importance[index]) ? Text('This is important') : Text('No it\'s not'),
          value: completedTasks.contains(task),
          onChanged: (bool value) {
           setState(() {
              if(!completedTasks.contains(task))
              {
                  completedTasks.add(task);
              }
              else
              {
                  completedTasks.remove(task);
              }
           });
          },
        ));
    }
  
  void addToDoItemScreen()
    {
      int index = tasks.length;
      while(importance.length > tasks.length)
      {
          importance.removeLast();   
      }
      importance.add(false);
      Navigator.of(context).push
      (
        new MaterialPageRoute(
         builder: (context) {
          return new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
              title: new Text('Add a new task')
            ),
            body: Form
            (child: Column
            (
              children: <Widget>
              [TextField
              (
                autofocus: true,
                onSubmitted: (name) {
                  addToDoItem(name);
                  //Navigator.pop(context); // Close the add todo screen
              },
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter something to do...',
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                border: OutlineInputBorder()
              ),
             ),
             TextField
             (
               //autofocus: true,
               onSubmitted: (val)
               {
                  addDescription(val, index);
               },
               decoration: new InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter a task decription...',
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                border: OutlineInputBorder()
              ),
             ),
             Center
             (
               child: Switch
               (
                  value: widget.data,
                  onChanged: (val)  
                  {
                    setState(() {
                      widget.data = val;
                      widget.data = !widget.data;
                      print(widget.data);
                    });
                    impTask(index);
                  },
               ),
             )
             ],
             ),)
             );
      }));
    }

    void addToDoItem(String task)
    {
        setState(() {
          tasks.add(task);
          descriptions.add("No description");
        });
    }

    void addDescription(String desc, int index)
    {
        setState(() {
          descriptions[index] = desc;
        });
    }

    void impTask(int index)
    {
        setState(() {
          if(importance[index])
          {
            importance[index] = false;
          }
          else 
          {
            importance[index] = true;
          }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you can watch this tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TYNbMnaEnmA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `StateFulBuilder` to the `addToDoItemScreen()`.

```
  void addToDoItemScreen() {
    int index = tasks.length;
    while (importance.length > tasks.length) {
      importance.removeLast();
    }
    importance.add(false);
    Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) { // this is new
        return new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('Add a new task')),
            body: Form(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextField(
                    autofocus: true,
                    onSubmitted: (name) {
                      addToDoItem(name);
                      //Navigator.pop(context); // Close the add todo screen
                    },
                    decoration: new InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Enter something to do...',
                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    //autofocus: true,
                    onSubmitted: (val) {
                      addDescription(val, index);
                    },
                    decoration: new InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Enter a task decription...',
                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Switch(
                      value: widget.data,
                      onChanged: (val) {
                        setState(() {
                          widget.data = val;
                        });
                        impTask(index);
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ));
      });
    }));
  }
```